# What is the probability density funcion of $Y=\ln(\sqrt {|X|})$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X$ is a uniformly distributed random variable between $(a,b)$.

What is the method to find the PDF of random variables like this ?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Comment: You will find in all probability textbooks the way to transform the pdf of RV $X$ into the pdf of RV $\varphi(X)$ is $\varphi$ is bijective and continuously differentiable : see paragraph "Dependent variables and change of variables" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function

Comment: Thanks but the method you mentioned requires g(X) to be monotonic. But here in my question we dont know if $\ln(\sqrt {|X|})$ is monotonic or not. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that:$$P\left(Y\leq y\right)=P\left(\ln\sqrt{\left|X\right|}\leq y\right)=P\left(\sqrt{\left|X\right|}\leq e^{y}\right)=P\left(\left|X\right|\leq e^{2y}\right)=F_X\left(e^{2y}\right)-F_X\left(-e^{2y}\right)$$

Differentiating gives: $$f_Y(y)=2e^{2y}\left(f_X\left(e^{2y}\right)+f_X\left(-e^{2y}\right)\right)\tag1$$

If $X$ is uniformly distribution on interval $\left(a,b\right)$
then $f_X$ is the function prescribed by $x\mapsto\frac{1}{b-a}$ if
$x\in\left(a,b\right)$ and $x\mapsto0$ otherwise.

If e.g. $a=1$ and $b=2$ then under $(1)$ you find the function prescribed by
$y\mapsto2e^{2y}$ if $y\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\ln2\right)$ and $y\mapsto0$
otherwise.

Comment: Your answer is so clear and understandable. Thank you very much

Comment: You are very welcome

Answer (score 0):

The general method for finding the PDF of $Y=\phi(X)$ is the following.

Consider :

$$E[Y]=E[f(X)] = \int_\mathbb{R} \phi(x) f(x) dx$$

with $f$ the PDF of $X$.

Now, you need to make the change of variable $u=\phi(x)$ (if such a change is correct) and after some simplifications, find something looking like :

$$E[Y] = \int_\mathbb{R} u g(u)du$$

Then the function $g$ is the PDF of $Y$.

Comment: Thanks a lot but the answer of @drhab is more understandable for me.